# powershell cisco access-list text manipulation

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with the following powershell script

I have a text based firewall config, I want to find the first object-group in the file and see if that exists in any access-lists within the same text file, if it does find the next object-group and keep looping through, until it outputs all object-groups that doesn't exist in any access-lists.

access-list Data in array $acl from text file

access-list outside extended permit object-group tcp_udp object-group domain_controllers object-group domain_controllers eq domain 
access-list outside extended permit object-group tcp_udp object-group domain_controllers_trusts object-group domain_controllers_trusts object-group active_directory 
access-list outside extended permit object-group tcp_udp object-group sccm_server object-group my_nets object-group smb 
access-list outside extended permit object-group tcp_udp object-group sccm_server object-group public_nets object-group rpc_endpoint 
access-list outside extended permit object-group tcp_udp object-group dmz_nets object-group domain_controllers object-group active_directory

object-group data in array $obg from text file

object-group service idrac tcp 
port-object range 5900 5901 
 port-object range 3668 3771 
 port-object range 5120 5123 
 port-object eq 7578 
 port-object eq https 
 port-object eq www 
object-group service admin_tcp tcp 
 port-object eq ssh 
 port-object eq https 
 port-object eq www 
 port-object eq 3389 
 port-object eq 445 
object-group network active_directory

```
$firewall = "fw1-live"

$fw = Get-Content C:\Software\netconfig\$firewall | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'remark'} | Set-Content "C:\Software\netconfig\outputs\$firewall"


$fw1 = Get-Content "C:\Software\netconfig\outputs\$firewall"
$fw1.GetType()
Foreach ($acl in $fw1)
        {
        If ($acl.StartsWith("access-list"))
            {
            $acl
            }
         }


Foreach ($obg in $fw1)
        {
        If ($obg.startswith("object-group")) 
            {
            $obg | Get-Unique } }

Get-Content $acl | where { $obg -notcontains $_}
```

this is where i'm stuck, please help

i hope this is clearer, please say if not ?

Comment: Instead of convoluted and confusing explanations simply add expected output (i.e. what the script should output if you feed it the input sample from the question).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for your data?

```
$text -like 'object-group *' -replace 'object-group '
```

The -like will filter it down to just the 'object-group' lines, and then the -replace will get rid of 'object-group ' from the line, leaving just the object group names.

The -like and -replace operators are working as array operators, so there's no need to do a foreach.  They'll handle the entire array at once.

Comment: this is what i'm after:  <br/>

Comment: That's about as clear as mud.  Give us some sample data and a sample of the results you expect the script to give you from that data.